# This page isn't working on domain, domain is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, cpanel, web-hosting, laravel-5.5, http-error

I am first time trying to host laravel 5.5 app using cpanel in a subdomain, but it giving me HTTP ERROR 500. Please somebody help me with step by step guide to host laravel in a subdomain. There is another website hosted on main domain probably developed in Joomla or might be in something else I am not aware of.[image]

Comment: It can be to many things to list, but if you check your laravel error log and web-server (apache or nginx) error logs you should be able to find what the problem is. Don't know cpanel, but expect that you can get error logs from some place

Answer (score 0):

to host laravel on subdomain using cPanel, you can use the subdomain feature in cPanel Main Menu.

the steps are :

1. upload your project folder into public_html
2. in cPanel main menu, choose Subdomains
3. on Create a Subdomain, type the name of the subdomain in Subdomain, and refer the Document Root into your project `public` folder. so the Document Root will be like *public_html/your-project-folder/public*
4. click Create button, and that's all

hope it's helps

Comment: already done this but still facing same issue